# If $f$ is a homomorphism, does it map $p$-groups to $p$-groups?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, p-groups

> If $f$ is a homomorphism s.t. $f:G \rightarrow H$, where $G$ and $H$ are finite groups, does it send $p$-groups in $G$ to $p$-groups in $H$?

I know isomorphisms send $p$-groups to $p$-groups, because they preserve order, and I know homomophisms preserve the order of elements. I think that means they also preserve subgroups, i.e. a subgroup $A \in G$ gets mapped to a subgroup $B$ of the same order in $H$ by $f$.

Is that correct?

Also, I think if $A$ is a normal subgroup, this doesn't imply $B$ is normal, unless $f$ is an isomorphism. This is because there could be an injective map from $G$ to $H$ where the order of $H$ is greater than the order of $G$.

Comment: I believe this is true even if $f$ is not surjective. Let $P$ be a p-subgroup of $G$. Then for every $x\in P$ satisfies $x^{p^n}=e$ for some $n$. Then $f(x)^{p^n}=f(x^{p^n})=f(e)=e$ which, by Lagrange's Theorem, implies that the order of $f(x)$ divides $p^n$ and is therefore also a power of $p$. So, $f(P)$ is also a p-group.

Comment: Not necessarily of the same order, since $f$ may not be injective. If $N$ is the kernel of $G$, then $f(H)\cong H/H\cap N$ by the isomorphism theorems, so the order of $f(H)$ divides the order of $H$. In particular, if $|H|=p^n$, then the image of $H$ has order $p^k$ for some $k$, hence is a $p$-subgroup.

Comment: If $f$ is surjective, then the image of a normal subgroup is always normal in $H$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin if $f$ is injective, then normal subgroups are not necessary normal in $H$, correct? since then the order of $H$ could be larger than the order of $G$

Comment: @Jess: If $f$ is not surjective then the image of a normal subgroup need not be normal in the target group, regardless of whether $f$ is injective or not.

Comment: I've changed the title, @Jess, to something more specific and helpful to other users than simply, "homomorphisms and $p$-groups," which is rather vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You don't specify if you are working with finite or infinite groups.</strike> The post has been edited to specify the groups are finite.

A $p$-group is a group in which every element has order a power of $p$. In the finite case, this is equivalent to the order of the group being a power of $p$, and so the argument given by Martund yields the desired result, regardless of whether $f$ is surjective or not.

More generally, if $f\colon G\to H$ is any group morphism and $g\in G$, then $|f(g)|$ divides $|g|$ for all $g\in G$, where $|x|$ denotes the order of $x$, and we take $|x|=0$ if $x$ is of infinite order (that is, $|x|$ is the nonnegative generator of the kernel of the map $\mathbb{Z}\to \langle x\rangle$ given by $n\longmapsto x^n$).

The divisibility result follows because if $g^k=e$, then $f(g)^k = f(g^k) = f(e) = e$; so the set of integers for which $f(g)^k=e$ is contained in the set of integers for which $g^k=e$. Thus, of $A$ is a subgroup of $G$ in which every element has order a power of $p$, $p$ a prime, then the same is true for $f(A)$. Thus, the image of a $p$-subgroup under a homomorphism is always a $p$-subgroup.

If $f$ is surjective (whether or not it is an isomorphism), then $f$ maps normal subgroups to normal subgroups. You can deduce this from the lattice homomorphism theorem, or directly: if $A\triangleleft G$, and $B=f(A)\leq H$, let $h\in H$ and $b\in B$. We want to show that $hbh^{-1}\in B$. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists $x\in G$ such that $f(x)=h$. And since $b\in f(A)$, there exists $a\in A$ with $f(a)=b$. Thus, $hbh^{-1}=f(x)f(a)f(x)^{-1} = f(xax^{-1})$. But since $A$ is normal in $G$, $xax^{-1}\in A$, so $f(xax^{-1})\in f(A)$. Thus, $hbh^{-1}\in f(A)$, as desired, hence $f(A)\triangleleft H$.

If $f$ is not surjective, though, then you cannot deduce that normal subgroups map to normal subgroups. For example, take $C_2$, the cyclic group of order $2$, and map to $S_3$ by mapping the generator to $(1,2)$. Then $C_2$ is normal in itself, but the image is not normal in $S_3$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\in G$ be a $p$-group. Restrict $f$ to $A$, kernel of this new homomorphism obtained is $A\cap \ker f$ and image is $f(A)$. Apply first isomorphism theorem, 
$$\Longrightarrow |A|=|A\cap \ker f|\times |f(A)|,$$
which implies that $f(A)$ is a $p$-group, if $A$ is a $p$-group.